# How to specify 'date' DataType for autogenerated WSDL?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, soap

I need a date (not a dateTime) to be passed to a web service,

I tried like that :

```
[WebMethod]
public void myMethod([XmlElementAttribute(DataType = "date")] DateTime someDate)
{
  // ...
}
```

But it still produce :

```
<tns:myMethod xsi:type="tns:myMethod">
    <someDate xsi:type="xsd:dateTime">dateTime</someDate>
</tns:myMethod>
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

In .NET, even the System.DateTime.Date is a DateTime data type ([documentaiton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date.aspx)).  There is no such thing as a "Date" datatype without the time in .NET.

The date portion of a DateTime will evaluate to midnight of that date, d

```
DateTime DateOnly = DateTime.Now.Date;
Console.Out.WriteLine(DateOnly.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
```

will write out

2012-09-10 00:00:00

Within your code you can access just the date using the code above, but regardless, it's going to be a DateTime value.

Of course, SOAP Encoding does have a Date datatype, but .NET has nothing to match it to, other than the DateTime Data Type.

*Unless you write your own data type, which would probably be a colossal waste of time.*

Comment: I am not looking for a Date .Net class, I just need that clients of my web service know they should provide a date (yyy-MM-dd) and not a dateTime (yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss).

Comment: I understand that. What I'm telling you is that ***as long as you're using the auto-generated wsdl***, you can't do it. The runtime will convert it to a datetime.